# How to use sed command to replace value in json file

Tags: shell, sed

My json file looks like this:

```
   "parameters": {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/2b06d50xxxxxedd021/resourceGroups/Reource1005/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                "connectionName": "azureblob",
                "connectionProperties": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                    }
                },
                "id": "/subscriptions/2b06d502-3axxxxxxedd021/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastasia/managedApis/azureblob"
            },
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/2b06d502xxxxxc8-5a8939edd021/resourceGroups/Reource1005/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                "connectionName": "office365",
                "id": "/subscriptions/2b06d50xxxxxx939edd021/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastasia/managedApis/office365"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to use **sed** command to replace the string in connectionId, currently my script is as follows:

```
script: 'sed -e ''/connectionId/c\ \"connectionId\" : \"/subscriptions/2b06d50xxxxb-92c8-5a8939edd021/resourceGroups/Reourcetest/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob\",'' "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/function-app-actions/templates/copycode.json"'
```

This script can replace the strings **in both connectionIds** in the json file with "Resourcetest", that's what I want to make the strings in the second connectionId replace with other values, how can I do that?

I'm new to sed commands, any insight is appreciated。

**Edit:**

I just want to replace "Resource1005" in both connectionId strings in the json file with "Resourcetest", but I need **other content in the  connectionIds string to keep the previous value**

So my expected output should look like this:

```
"connectionId": "/subscriptions/2b06d502-3axxxx8939edd021/resourceGroups/Reourcetest/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob"


"connectionId": "/subscriptions/2b06d502-3axxxx8939edd021/resourceGroups/Reourcetest/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365"
```

If I use the script I mentioned above, it does replace the two Resource1005s, but the other values in the string are also replaced with the same (I just want to replace the Resource1005 value)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention your sample of output like **from** which string **to** which string you want to substitute? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13， thanks so much to looking into this, I've edited the original question, please check it out, much appreciate!

Comment: Thanks for update, I have posted an answer, we can discuss is there, cheers @Edison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples and attempts, please try following GNU `awk` code. This will print only edited lines(as per shown samples) in output with substituting `Resource1005` with `Resourcetest` in values.

```bash
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+"connectionId": "[^"]*' '
RT{
  sub(/\n+[[:space:]]+/,"",RT)
  sub(/\/Resource1005\//,"/Resourcetest/",RT)
  print RT
}
'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With `sed` you can try following `sed` code.

```bash
sed -nE 's/(^[[:space:]]+"connectionId": ".*)\/Resource1005\/(.*)/\1\/Resourcetest\/\2/p' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, I currently use the command to globally replace this value, which seems to meet my needs(I've added to the original question) I've accepted the answer, thanks again! cheers

Comment: @Edison, Questions are not meant to have answers in them so I rolled back your edit in it.

Comment: @Edison, Also IMHO solution you have found could have issues, since you are NOT checking on which line and on which section of Input_file you are substituting it, imagine a situation where these values are on some other lines? Then also it will substitute them. On other hand my solution checks and makes sure then substitution happens on right line only.

Comment: ok, got it, New to SO forums :)

Comment: @Edison, no problem we all learn from each other. Please go through my previous comment about my solution's explanation that will help you to understand why I made/used regex in my code to match exact section in your Input_file, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Common practice is to create template files and change them with `sed` or something else. Like this for example:

```
cat template.json
...
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "__CONNECTIONID__",
                "connectionName": "office365",
                "id": "__ID__"
            }
...

sed 's|__CONNECTIONID__|/some/path|; s|__ID__|/some/other/path|' template.json > new.json
```